# Applying repository method to relationship models

Tags: laravel, eloquent, repository-pattern

I have 2 repo's for Taxonomy and its child Terms. Ive setup interfaces and so forth and been working through some code to clean it up and remove eloquent from my controllers thus also making them skinny.

I am struggling to get my head around how to apply methods to the child relationship without getting errors. Please go easy im learning this but feel im missing something glaringly obvious and going around in circles losing track of everything ive tried up to now.

**MyController.php**

```
$taxonomy = $taxonomies->findBySlug($this->taxonomy_name);

if ( isset($taxonomy->id) ) {

    // The below line worked and what im trying to replace below to remove firstOrCreate from my controller

    //$taxonomy->term()->firstOrCreate(array('name' => $request->name, 'slug' => str_slug($request->name)));

    $taxonomy->term()->createTermFromSlug($request->name);
}
```

**TaxonomyInterface.php**

```
interface TaxonomyInterface{

    public function createTermFromSlug($term_name);
}
```

**DBTaxonomyRepository**

```
class DBTaxonomyRepository 
extends AbstractDBRepository 
implements TaxonomyInterface
{

    protected $table = 'taxonomy';

    public $timestamps = false;

    public function term()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Repositories\DBTaxonomyTermRepository', 'taxonomy_id', 'id');
    }

    /**
     * Create term based on unique slug.
     *
     * @param $term_name
     * @internal param $name
     */
    public function createTermFromSlug($term_name)
    {
        $term = $this->firstOrCreate(array(
            'slug' => str_slug($term_name)
        ));

        $term->name = $term_name;

        $term->save();
    }
}
```

I have tried so many things now im clearly missing something fundamental where I can't just learn it through trial and error. This is the current state I have left it.

In a nutshell I would like to apply repository methods to a taxonomy entity for its term entities thus decoupling eloquent from the controller.

I wish to abstract this after so that I can reuse it throughout a variety of different controllers handling differing Taxonomies.

Comment: Does `AbstractDBRepository` extend Eloquent?

Comment: Yes.

`use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

abstract class AbstractDBRepository extends Model`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the way you are dumping everything into your repositories, I think you are just trading one problem (fat controllers) for another problem (god class repositories that try to do too much).

I would structure this a little bit differently so that your repositories are not also your models but instead have the models injected into your repository.  Here would be an example repository.

```
use App\Terms;
use App\Taxonomy;

class TaxonomyRepository
{
    protected $term;
    protected $taxonomy;

    // Here we are injecting your Term and Taxonomy models
    public function __construct(Term $term, Taxonomy $taxonomy)
    {
        $this->term = $term;
        $this->taxonomy = $taxonomy;
    }

    /**
     * Create term based on unique slug.
     *
     * @param $term_name
     * @internal param $name
     */
    public function createTermFromSlug($term_name)
    {
        $term = $this->term->firstOrCreate([
            'slug' => str_slug($term_name)
        ]);

        $term->name = $term_name;

        $term->save();
    }

    public function findTaxonomyBySlug($slug)
    {
        return $this->taxonomy->where('slug', $slug)->first();
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if you still need the extends and implements so I left them out.

Then you just inject your repository into your controller...

```
class MyController
{
    protected $taxRepo;

    // Here we are injecting your Repository into the controller
    public function __construct(TaxonomyRepository $taxRepo)
    {
        $this->taxRepo = $taxRepo;
    }

    public function store(Reques $request)
    {
        $taxonomy = $this->taxRepo->findTaxonomyBySlug($this->taxonomy_name);

        if ( isset($taxonomy->id) ) {
            $this->taxRepo->createTermFromSlug($request->name);
        }
    }
}
```

The idea is simple.  Each class should only do one thing (and hopefully do it well).  Where one class depends on another (for example the repository would require the term and tax models), have Laravel inject them for you.

Comment: Yes I was beginning to think it was getting a bit messy already and wasn't completely comfortable with it. I did try to begin with something similar but ran into problems and ended up down this path.

This looks a nice way to go. Will give this a try and report back. Many thanks.

Comment: Got the time to do a variation of this and it worked a treat! Much better. I wrapped it up in an overall Service. Thanks very much. Greatly appreciated.